# Reshaping long with pivot_longer() with multiple values_to

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape

I am trying to reshape long the following dataset:

```
country  Data Type       Product   2007    [...]   2021
Austria  Retail Volume    id1      125             140
Austria  Retail Value     id1      15000           12000
Austria  Retail Volume    id2      75              25
```

I would like to reshape it (with pivot_longer(), no reshape for the sake of God) having two values_to,
one for the Retail Volume and one for the Retail Value! How can I do this?

```
country  Product   Year    Retail Volume Retail Value   
Austria      id1      2007            
Austria      id1      2007         
Austria      id2      2007
```

The problem is that values_to must be of dimension 1!

I tried pivot_longer(), tried different posts, no help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to do a `pivot_longer`, then do a `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyr)

dat |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(matches("\\d{4}")) |> 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = c(Data, Type), values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   country Product name  Retail_Volume Retail_Value
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>         <int>        <int>
#> 1 Austria id1     2007            125        15000
#> 2 Austria id1     2021            140        12000
#> 3 Austria id2     2007             75           NA
#> 4 Austria id2     2021             25           NA
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
country  Data Type       Product   2007    2021
Austria  Retail Volume    id1      125             140
Austria  Retail Value     id1      15000           12000
Austria  Retail Volume    id2      75              25           
", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you'll have to `pivot_longer()` first, then `pivot_wider()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~country, ~Data_Type, ~Product, ~`2007`, ~`2021`,
  "Austria", "Retail Volume", "id1", 125, 140,
  "Austria", "Retail Value", "id1", 15000, 12000,
  "Austria", "Retail Volume", "id2", 765, 25,
)

df  |> 
  pivot_longer(
    c(`2007`, `2021`),
    names_to = "year",
    values_to = "value"
  ) |> 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Data_Type,
    values_from = value
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   country Product year  `Retail Volume` `Retail Value`
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>           <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 Austria id1     2007              125          15000
#> 2 Austria id1     2021              140          12000
#> 3 Austria id2     2007              765             NA
#> 4 Austria id2     2021               25             NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not think about it... Well, yes, I am a novice :)